# Recursive approach to Persistent bugger problem returns undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've been trying to solve the following problem in codewars using recursion:

> Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.
> For example (Input --> Output):

```
39 --> 3 (because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4 = 4 and 4 has only one digit)
999 --> 4 (because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126, 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2)
4 --> 0 (because 4 is already a one-digit number)
```

Here's what I've tried:

```js
var numOfIterations = 0;
function persistence(num) {
   //code me
  var i;
  var digits=[];
  var result = 1;
  if (num.toString().length==1) {
    return numOfIterations;
  } else {
      numOfIterations++;
      digits = Array.from(String(num), Number);
      for (i=0;i<digits.size;i++) {
        result=result*digits[i];
      }
      persistence(result);
    }
}
```

But for some reason, instead of returning the number of iterations, it returns undefined.  I've been told that I'm not using recursion correctly, but I just can't find the problem.

Comment: The `else` block never returns anything...

Comment: I see. But I though since I've called the persistence function inside the else block it will iterate until the length is 1, so it can finally return the number of iterations.

Comment: @downmath take a look to my answer. I think that is what you are looking for. If you need some explanation you can ask me

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have explained what's wrong with your code.  I just want to point out a simpler implementation:

```js
const multiplyDigits = (n) =>
  n < 10 ? n : (n % 10) * multiplyDigits (n / 10 | 0);

const persistence = (n) =>
  n < 10 ? 0 : 1 + persistence (multiplyDigits (n));

[39, 999, 4] .forEach (t => console .log (`${t}:\t${persistence (t)}`));
```

`multiplyDigits` does just what it says, recursively multiplying the final digit by the number left when you remove that last digit (Think of `| 0` as like Math .floor), and stopping when n is a single digit.

`persistence` checks to see if we're already a single digit, and if so, returns zero.  If not, we add one to the value we get when we recur on the multiple of the digits.

Comment: @Mulan: thanks.  That's probably a good idea.  I just want an integer division operator in the languages for cases like this!  Fixed

Comment: agreed. super clean. love the recursive expression <3

Answer (score 1):

> I've been told that I'm not using recursion correctly

You're recursing, but you're not *returning the result* of that recursion.  Imagine for a moment just this structure:

```
function someFunc() {
  if (someCondition) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    anotherFunc();
  }
}
```

If `someCondition` is `false`, what does `someFunc()` return?  Nothing.  So it's result is `undefined`.

Regardless of any recursion, at its simplest if you want to return a result from a function then you need to `return` it:

```
function persistence(num) {
  //...
  if (num.toString().length==1) {
    //...
  } else {
    //...
    return persistence(result); // <--- here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @David wrote in his answer, you were missing the return of the recursive call to itself.

Plus you were using  `digits.size` instead of `digits.length`.

Anyway consider that one single digit being zero will collpse the game because that's enough to set the result to zero despite how many digits the number is made of.

To deal with the reset of `numOfIterations`, at first I tried using `function.caller` to discriminate between recursive call and direct call and set the variable accordingly. Since that method is deprecated as shown here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

I opted for the optional argument `iteration` that gets set to zero as default, to keep track of that value while it goes down the call stack. This solution still fulfills the fact that the caller doesn't need to know a new interface for the function to work.

```js
//var numOfIterations = 0;

function persistence(num, iteration=0) {

  /*
  Commented strategy using the function.caller
  working but deprecated so I can't recommend anymore
  used optional argument iteration instead
  
  //gets the name of the caller scope
  let callerName = persistence.caller?.name;
  //if it's different from the name of this function
  if (callerName !== 'persistence')
    //reset the numOfIterations
    numOfIterations = 0;
  */
     
  var digits=[];  
  if (num.toString().length==1){  
    return iteration;    
  } else {    
    var result = 1;    
    digits = Array.from(String(num), Number);
    for (let i=0;i<digits.length;i++) {
      result = result * digits[i];
    }
    return persistence(result, iteration+1);
  }
}

console.log( persistence(39) );        //-> 3
console.log( persistence(999 ) );      //-> 4
console.log( persistence(4) );         //-> 0
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it, sorta... the problem now is that I don't know how to reset the number of iterations so that if I, say, call the persistence function twice consecutively, it doesn't return the same number of iterations given by the last instance of the function.

Comment: yes that's quite a weakness. Anyway to keep it simple you could reset that var one moment before calling persistence from the entry point. Or you could add that number in the chain of args to persistence. I changed the answer including the first approach

Comment: I'm afraid the first approach wouldn't work since in codewars you don't get to call the function yourself, the system of the website does if for you, so there's no choice other than for the function instances to be called consecutively. But could you elaborate on the second approach? I didn't quite get it.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a strategy that keeps track of the iteration number pushing its value down the recursive calls so there's no need to access any variable outside the function scope anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
const persistenceTailRecursive = (num, iterations = 0) => {
  const str = '' + num;
  if(str.length === 1){
    return iterations;
  }
  return persistenceTailRecursive(str.split('').reduce((res, a) => res * parseInt(a), 1), iterations + 1)
}

const persistence = (num) => {
  const str = '' + num;
  if(str.length === 1){
    return 0;
  }
  return  1 + persistence(str.split('').reduce((res, a) => res * parseInt(a), 1))
}

console.log(persistenceTailRecursive(93))
console.log(persistenceTailRecursive(999))

console.log(persistence(93))
console.log(persistence(999))
```

There are 2 versions

**1 tailRecursive** call the same method with the exact signature (preventing stackoverflow in some languages like scala)

**2 basic** the result is calculated at the end